# redirecting domain to subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, domain, redirect, directory, root

I'm new to using and changing the workings of a server and all that.
So far I've only had one server with one domain for myself, but now a business is getting some traction and I want to use a different domain for it while keeping it on my server.

The situation is like this:

I have the main domain and root directory like **maindomain.com**. I also just bought **projectdomain.com**.

The files for **projectdomain.com** are within **maindomain.com/project/**.

I have established a forward from **projectdomain.com** to **maindomain.com/project/** already, but I can't access sites via the url.

For example:

I wan't to type **projectdomain.com/somecontent/** and access **maindomain.com/project/somecontent** while maintaining the projectdomain.com link in the adress bar.

When I try it now I always end up in **maindomain.com/project/** and never in the file I specified in the url.

I've tried working around it with the .htaccess file, but don't really know much about it. What I have now is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?projectdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://maindomain.com/project/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Sorry for the noob question, I really don't know much about the topic and I'm not sure what to google to get what I want.

Comment: Just wondering, if this is your own server, why you are using a subdirectory off the main domain for this project (for which you have a separate domain) rather than using an entirely different area of the filesystem? Are the main site and this project site somehow connected?

Comment: You should set the document root correctly, not use a rewrite.

Comment: I'm puttint it all on public_html folder because my server provider told me to.

Comment: How would I change the document root correctly?
I'm not sure if that is the way to go as maindomain.com should still got to the root's index, I just want projectdomain.com to go to a different folder where the project is